# How i can return a specific status + message in node/adonis?

Tags: node.js, adonis.js

I'm trying to return a specific response status and one message when my api get's a error.

I try this way:

```
return response.status(409).json({message: 'User already registered'})
```

But i'm receiving:

```
response is not defined
```

I try importing the response:

```
const response = use('Adonis/Src/Response')
```

But this way i receive:

> response.status is not a function

Comment: The code is in a controller?

Comment: @CrBast yes, is in a controller

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `response` object from controller :

**Controller**

```js
class MyController {
    async login({ response }) {
        return response.status(409).json({message: 'User already registered'})
    }
}
```

**Route**

```js
Route.get('/users', async ({ response }) => {
  return response.status(409).json({message: 'User already registered'})
})
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this on your provider or hooks, this was stated on [docs](https://adonisjs.com/docs/4.1/response#_extending_response)

```js
const Response = use('Adonis/Src/Response')

Response.macro('send409', function (data) {
  this.status(409).send(data)
})
```

Comment: in the documentation have a list of methods (continue, ok, switching protocols...) but how i can use this methods? i don't need to create my own method, i need to use the adonis methods list response

Comment: Just use it `response.conflict('your data goes here')`